# Run Multiple HTTP Requests One After Another and Return Observable

Tags: angular, api, observable, httprequest, mergemap

I have two observable request functions below and although it works, I need the fire print to run after the newOrder api and return the observable. I tried using mergeMap but it just skipped through without providing any error.

```js
postNewOrder(id: string, item: Item) {
  this.cloverMerchantIdAndTokenSet();
    
  const body = {
    'order_id': id,
    'item': Item
  };
    
  const newOrder = this.http.post<Order>(`${environment.apiUrl}/orders/createOrder`, body);
  const printOrder = this.fireOrder(id);
    
  return forkJoin(newOrder, printOrder);
}
    
fireOrder(id: string) {
  this.cloverMerchantIdAndTokenSet();
  const body = {
    'order_id': id
  };
  return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/Orders/print`, body);
}
```

for mergeMap, the code is all the same just instead of returning the fork of the 2 requests, I did:

```js
return newLineItem.pipe(
  mergeMap(Response => printOrder)
);
```

Comment: You say you tried with mergeMap, could you show us please? We can only help debug code we see...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)

```
postNewOrder(id: string, item: Item) {
   this.cloverMerchantIdAndTokenSet();

    const body = {
      'order_id': id,
      'item': Item
    };

    const newOrder = this.http.post<Order>(`${environment.apiUrl}/orders/createOrder`, body);

    return newOrder.pipe(switchMap(res => this.fireOrder(res.id));
  }
```

Comment: When I use this it works but the issue is the order created is missing notes and modifiers but if I do it with the forkjoin, it works fine.

Comment: @z123 updated my answer, maybe this might fix it

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: Hey, I believe I found the issue, if you look at my post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73612910/best-way-to-like-multiple-dependant-http-requests-without-multiple-subscribes, the issue is when I link then with switchmap, the updateModifications api is not called so the order is places without modifications. Is there any way I can incorporate that addModifications api so it creates the order, then adds modifications and finally prints?

Comment: @z123 the code provided is incomplete, I cant find updateModifications method, please just add another switchmap like so `newOrder.pipe(switchMap(res => this.updateModifications(res.id).pipe(switchMap(() => this.fireOrder(res.id)))))`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are returning the function instead of calling it and returning the result.

```
return newLineItem.pipe(
      mergeMap(Response => printOrder())
    );
```