# Best Way to Link Multiple dependant HTTP Requests Without Multiple Subscribes and Loops

Tags: node.js, angular, api, http

I have an angular project and I have some api that creates a line item and then loops through and calls the api to add each modification to the line item and finally it fires the print request. Right now I have to do this using multiple subscribes and was thinking if there was away to modify the service itself so it runs the api's in order and returns the response so it shortens the code as well. The loops make it a bit complicated for exhaustmap or mergemap.

The function in my component that calls the api's in order are:

```
addLineItems() {
    this.lineItems = this.lineItems.filter(function (item) {
      delete item.image;
      return true;
    });
    console.log('In Line items' + this.orderId);

    this.storedMerchantId  = this.currentUser.merchantId
    this.storedCloverToken  = this.currentUser.cloverToken;

    console.log('line Item Is: ' + JSON.stringify(this.lineItems));

    this.lineItems.forEach(lineItem => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(lineItem));
      this.cloverOrderService
        .postNewLineItem(
          this.orderId,
          lineItem,
          this.storedMerchantId
        )
        .subscribe(cloverItem => {
          lineItem.id = cloverItem[0].id;
          console.log(JSON.stringify(lineItem));
          lineItem.newModifications.forEach(modification => {
            this.cloverOrderService
              .postNewModification(
                this.orderId,
                lineItem.id,
                modification,
                this.storedMerchantId
              )
              .pipe(first())
              .subscribe(itemModification => {
                console.log(
                  'modification added:' +
                  JSON.stringify(itemModification)
                );
              },
                error => {
                  this.alertService.error(error);
                  this.loading = false;
                });
          });
          console.log(JSON.stringify(lineItem));
          this.cartService.SetOrderHistoryToCart();
          this.cartService.removeFromCart(lineItem);
        });
    });
    this.orderPlaced();
  }
```

The code for the service functions for the api calls are:

```
postNewLineItem(id: string, lineItem: LineItem, merchantId: string) {
   this.cloverMerchantIdAndTokenSet();

    const body = {
      'merchant_id': this.merchant_id,
      'token': this.cloverToken,
      'order_id': id,
      'line_item': lineItem
    };

    const newLineItem = this.http.post<CloverOrder>(`${environment.apiUrl}/cloverOrders/createLineItem`, body);
    const printOrder = this.fireOrder(id, merchantId);

    //return forkJoin(newLineItem, printOrder);


    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/cloverOrders/createLineItem`, body);
  }

  fireOrder(id: string, merchantId: string) {
    this.cloverMerchantIdAndTokenSet();
    const body = {
      'merchant_id': this.merchant_id,
      'token': this.cloverToken,
      'printItem': new PrinterObject('PrintOrder', id),
      'order_id': id
    };
    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/cloverOrders/firePrint`, body);
  }

  postNewModification(id: string, lineItemID: string, modification: Modification, merchantID: string) {
   this.cloverMerchantIdAndTokenSet();
    const body = {
      // 'merchant_id': localStorage.getItem('merchant_id'),
      'merchant_id': this.merchant_id,
      'token': this.cloverToken,
      'order_id': id,
      'lineitem_id': lineItemID,
      'modification': modification
    };
    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/cloverOrders/createItemModification`, body);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you need to know that `from` enables you to transform an array into a stream, then the stream contains an element of the array, the next problem is abuse of `subscribe`. You should `pipe` the value and transform by `rxjs operators`

I've created an example, how you can use a `from` instead of a `loop`.

```
 function fromInsteadLoop() {
  const items = [1, 2, 3];

  from(items)
    .pipe(map((item) => item + 1))
    .subscribe((item) => {
      console.log(item);
      // console.log(item) -> 2
      // console.log(item) -> 3
      // console.log(item) -> 4
    });
   }
```

Also I've created solution but I'm not sure it's good:

```
from(this.lineItems)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((lineItem) => {
      return zip(
        this.cloverOrderService.postNewLineItem(
          this.orderId,
          lineItem,
          this.storedMerchantId
        ),
        of(lineItem)
      );
    }),
    mergeMap(([_, lineItem]) => {
      return from(
        lineItem.newModifications.map((modification) => ({
          modification,
          lineItem,
        }))
      );
    }),
    mergeMap(({ modification, lineItem }) => {
      return this.cloverOrderService.postNewModification(
        this.orderId,
        lineItem.id,
        modification,
        this.storedMerchantId
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: (itemModification) => console.log(itemModification),
    error: (error) => {
      this.alertService.error(error);
      this.loading = false;
    },
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, although the above code worked, I am getting a 500 on post new modifications endpoint. The reason seems to be that the lineItem.id is returning null for the postNewModification() call. That lineitem Id is returned from the postNewLineItem() api call response. Can you please tell me how that can be passed through the mergeMaps. Also, wouldn't concatMap work better in this case because they are dependant requests?

Comment: You have to take a response from `postNewLineItem` and modify lineItem about this response from API

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Higher Order Operators from `RxJs` to transform multiple streams and subscribe only once. You can choose an operator such as `mergeMap`, `switchMap` or `concatMap` among others, it depends on what you want to do with your different streams and the relation between them. As stated in the learnRxJs official website:

> For instance, when using switchMap each inner subscription is
> completed when the source emits, allowing only one active inner
> subscription. In contrast, mergeMap allows for multiple inner
> subscriptions to be active at a time. Because of this, one of the most
> common use-case for mergeMap is requests that should not be canceled,
> think writes rather than reads. Note that if order must be maintained
> concatMap is a better option.

Read [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) for how to use them with exmaples and what is best for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response but can you provide an example of how I can use concatMap in my case. I have been looking into it and trying it but I cant find any example of linking multiple requests using it.